# No operator matches the given name and argument types. - Django F() expression

Tags: python, django, postgresql, expression

I'm trying to add UTM paramaters to every single `link` rows in my `Postgresql` database using Django's `F() expression` but I keep getting an `operator does not exist: character varying + unknown.` error.

Here's the function I'm trying to apply from my views.py:

```
def utm_param(request):
    if request.GET.get('mybtn'):  # to improve, == 'something':

        Product.objects.all().update(link=F('link') + '?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref')

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: character varying + unknown LINE 1: ...link" = ("search_product"."link" + '?utm_so... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

And the arrow from the traceback is pointing towards the `+`.

How can this be fixed?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`Concat`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) here, to concatenate strings:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Product.objects.update(
    link=Concat(F('link'), Value('?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref'))
)
```

That being said, the above here will append `'?utm_source=uvergo&amp;utm_medium=ref'` to *every* link, even if these already contain `'?utm_source=uvergo&amp;utm_medium=ref'`.

You can prevent adding this a second time by excluding those with an [**`__endswith`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#endswith):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Product.objects.exclude(
    link__endswith='?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref'
).update(
    link=Concat(F('link'), Value('?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this now! Will this work with bulk updating?

Comment: @locq: yes, but as said, it might not be ideal to do this, since if you update a second time, some links might contain `'?utm_source=uvergo&amp;utm_medium=ref?utm_source=uvergo&amp;utm_medium=ref'`.

Comment: Okay and can this be ignored if it already exists within the row with an if statement?

Comment: @locq: you can exclude those from the queryset you update. But is it necessary to update in the first place? Why not *render* the url with the querystring?